# How do I view podcasts in a tiled artwork view using iTunes?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

I upgraded from iTunes 10 to 11 and the view for my podcasts has changed.

Is it possible to bring back the old tile view of my podcasts?

The only option appears to be the list view on the side and only a view of the individual podcast to the right of that. I want to see the overall view in tile form again.

Comment: If you try to select view options in the Podcast view - you will see an empty space where hopefully options will arrive. This product was delayed a month for engineering work - perhaps that view had problems and was cut so that the rest of the App could be released. http://cl.ly/LI7h I would send http://apple.com/feedback in case they can add that back.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a smart playlist where Media Kind Is Podcast, and I view that in Grid View.